# Cумма элементов

Tags: javascript, html5

Пытаюсь вычислить значение и отправить его в инпут. Но считает оно его как не 7.082 + 10 + 10 , а просто добавляет 10 в конце, как будто это текст.

```
<script>
    function krsp() 
      {
       var  kolrap = document.getElementById('kolrap').value ;
       var priladka = document.getElementById('priladka').value ;
       var procent = document.getElementById('procent').value;
       document.getElementById('kolrsp').value = document.getElementById('kolrap').value * document.getElementById('procent').value / 100 + (document.getElementById('kolrap').value + document.getElementById('priladka').value) ;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: А зачем вы заводите переменные, если в дальнейшем не используете и расчет пытаетесь вести через .value?

Comment: html код добавьте

Comment: попробуй явно преобразовать значения input'ов в число parseFloat(document.getElementById('kolrap').value)

Comment: А через что лучше вести расчет?

Comment: Преобразование помогло, спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите, как этот кусок кода привести в разумный вид?

Answer (score 2):

Вы добавляете `string` а не число.

```
function krsp() {
    var kolrap = parseFloat(document.getElementById('kolrap').value);
    var priladka = parseFloat(document.getElementById('priladka').value);
    var procent = parseFloat(document.getElementById('procent').value);
    document.getElementById('kolrsp').value = kolrap * procent / 100 + kolrap + priladka;
}
```